# Переконвертация UTF8 <> 1251 и большая буква "И"

Tags: java, utf-8, кодировка, cp1251

Берем строку "Игра!" и переводим в массив байт (1).
Создаём строку, из этого массива байт, но указываем "неверную" кодировку(2).
В итоге получаем строку с "поехавшей кодировкой"(utf8AsW1251 ).

Выполняем обратные действия(3). 
и видим что строка переконвертировалась нормально за исключение большой буквы "И". Почему большая буква "И" отображается как �? ?

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class Main {
private static final Charset CS_1251 = Charset.forName("windows-1251");
private static final Charset CS_UTF8 = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String in = "Игра!";
    byte[] bytesUtf8 = in.getBytes(CS_UTF8);                    //(1)
    String utf8AsW1251 = new String(bytesUtf8, CS_1251);        //(2) 

    System.out.println("utf8 bytes as 1251: " + utf8AsW1251);   //utf8 bytes as 1251: Р�РіСЂР°!

    System.out.println(
            new String(utf8AsW1251.getBytes(CS_1251), CS_UTF8)  //(3) 
    );                                                          //�?гра!
}
```

}

Comment: Действительно интересно. Проверила в цикле все русские буквы. Такая проблема наблюдается только с заглавной буквой "И". Очень любопытно. Присоединяюсь к вопросу...

Comment: Сами же указали неверную кодировку. С таким же успехом можно "перевернуть" вопрос. Почему все буквы остались правильными, кроме "И", которая как и положено испортилась?:)

Comment: Ну в данном случае "неверная кодировка" используется для шифрования строки. Однако вот дешифратор, построенный на выполнении обратных действий дает сбой на букве И. Так что вопрос то вполне корректный :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> – Доктор, когда я делаю так, у меня болит
>   – Не делайте так

Буква `И` кодируется в `utf-8` как последовательность байтов `0xd0, 0x98`

Код `0xd0` соответствует символу `Р` в кодировке `cp1251`, а вот код `0x98` не соответствует никакому символу, он просто отсутствует в кодировке, поэтому вместо несуществующего символа будет подставлен [заменяющий](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB). Получится строка `Р�`.

Cимвол � тоже отсутсвует в `cp1251`, поэтому при повторном кодировании будет заменен на `?` (с кодом `0x3f`), получаем последовательность байтов `0xd0, 0x3f`.

При декодировании сталкиваемся еще с одной проблемой: последовательность `0xd0, 0x3f` недопустима в `utf-8`, поэтому теперь уже вместо `0xd0` будет подставлен заменяющий символ, в итоге получается строка `�?`

С остальными буквами такого может и не произойти, но это не значит, что подобные манипуляции всегда будут приводить к правильному результату

`Й` → `0xd0, 0x99` → `Р™` → `0xd0, 0x99` → `Й`